# Apply Wordpress function on specific page id(s)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, hook-woocommerce

I would like to apply the function below to three specific Woocommerce category page. For example (cat-a, cat-b, cat-c) Can I address them via Page ID, Slug, or somehow?

```
function remove_some_widgets(){
    unregister_sidebar( 'shop-sidebar' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'remove_some_widgets', 11 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ispage()`

```
function remove_some_widgets(){
    if(is_page()){
        unregister_sidebar( 'shop-sidebar' );
    }
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'remove_some_widgets', 11 );
```

As it is above, this will apply no any single page. You can add parameters to `is_page()` as you need:

// When any single Page is being displayed.
is_page();

// When Page 42 (ID) is being displayed.
is_page( 42 );

// When the Page with a post_title of "Contact" is being displayed.
is_page( 'Contact' );

// When the Page with a post_name (slug) of "about-me" is being displayed.
is_page( 'about-me' );

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/

Comment: Can also use is_category() in the same way. Or mix both